# Chart.js horizontalBar start bars from custom value

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Chart.js horizontalBar.

I need to start the chart from custom value and not zero or lowest number in data, but could not found any way how to achieve this.

```
beginAtZero: true // I need this to start not from zero, but from my predefined value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Min value and a Max value for every axis, in this case you should set it for xAxes

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        Min: 5,
        Max: 10,
       }
     }]
   }
}
```

You can set also a suggestedMin and a suggestedMax that will be ignored if the dataset data exceed the values

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        suggestedMin: 5, // If the actual min value in your dataset is minor of 5, this property will be ignored
        suggestedMax: 10, // If the actual max value in your dataset is major of 10, this property will be ignored
       }
     }]
   }
}
```

Check the [Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings) for more info